# How to create Deltas in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BQ which I refresh on daily basis. It's a full snapshot every day. 
I have a business requirement to create deltas of that feed. 
Table Details :
Table contains 10 columns
Out of 10 columns, 5 columns change on daily basis. How do I identify which columns changed and only create a snapshot for that? 
For eg here are the columns in tableA: columns which will frequently change are in **bold**.

Custid - ABC

first_product - toy

first_product_purchase_date - 2015-01-01

**last_product** - ebook

**last_product_purchase_date** - 2018-05-01

**second_product** - Magazine

**second_product_purchase_date** - 2016-01-01

**third_product** - null

**third_product_purchase_date** - null

**fourth_product** - null

**fourth_product_purchase_date** - null

After more purchase Data will look like this:

Custid - ABC

first_product - toy

first_product_purchase_date - 2015-01-01

**last_product** - Hardbook

**last_product_purchase_date** - 2018-05-17

**second_product** - Magazine

**second_product_purchase_date** - 2016-01-01

**third_product** - CD

**third_product_purchase_date** - 2017-01-01

**fourth_product** - null

**fourth_product_purchase_date** - null

first_product = first product ever purchased
last_product = most recent product purchased

This is just one row of records for one customer. I have millions of customers with all these columns, and let's say half a million of the rows will be updated on daily basis.

In my delta, I just want the rows where any of the column value changed.

Comment: You need sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have updated the question with sample data

Comment: still darkness here. you might want to elaborate more on "which I refresh on daily basis." - what exactly and how you do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a column for each product bought and their repetition,  perhaps this comes from a de-normalize dimensional models. To query the last "update" you would have to compare each columns the previous row by using the [lead](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#lead) function. This would use a lot of computation and might not be optimal.

I recommend using [repeated](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated#example) fields. The product and product_purchase_date would be repeated field and you could simply query using a `where product_purchase_date = current_date()` which would use much less computation.

De-normalize dimensional models are meant to use less computation on traditional data warehouses. Bigquery being fast, highly scalable, enterprise data warehouse has a lot of computing power.

To have a beter understanding on how BigQuery works under the hood I recommend reviewing this [document](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/01/bigquery-under-the-hood).